# Excel formula to match digits after concatenation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, array-formulas

[image]

In the above image, I want to check on which row the input 1,2,3 & 4 are matching. So in this example I want result 3 as it has "1 1 0 0" and the box on the top also has "1 1 0 0".

I tried following array formula but it's not working.

> =IF((C10:C25=C3)*(D10:D25=C4)*(E10:E25=C5)*(F10:F25=C6),G10:G25,"")

It would be great if this can be done without using any intermediate result columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your first list is in B2:B5 and the bigger grid in D2:G17, with the result column in H2:H17, use this array formula:

```
=INDEX(H2:H17,MATCH(B2&B3&B4&B5,D2:D17&E2:E17&F2:F17&G2:G17,0))
```